# HTTP/1.1 300 Multiple Choices error - tags [redirect], [url-redirection] and [http-redirect]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

I just found a question [that featured all three tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38004540/1270789); [redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redirect) seems like the main tag, so can someone suggest the other two as synonyms? There's about 2,500 questions with the other two tags but just six followers, so I think [url-redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-redirection) and [http-redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-redirect) should be merged into [redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redirect).

For the time being, I have deleted the other two tags on the question.

Comment: I went ahead and suggested [url-redirection] as a synonym of [\[redirect\]](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/redirect/synonyms), so if anyone wants to vote on that.. I couldn't do that with [http-redirect] though, because someone thought it would be a good idea trying to synonymize all [http-*] tags with [\[http\]](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/http/synonyms)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[http-redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-redirect) is currently suggested as a synonym for [http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http), so we can't proceed on that.

Floern has opened up [a suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/redirect/synonyms) to synonymize [redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redirect) with [url-redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-redirection) which people with sufficient tag score can vote on.

Comment: So is it possible to make `redirect` and `url-redirection` synonym for `http-redirect` (which is already a synonym)? Because I think it's the most meaningful out of the three...

Comment: I voted for to mark `url-redirection` as synonym. I also voted against `http-redirection` as synonym of `http`, frankly it seems a better synonym for `redirect`.